# I am developing an app to test download/upload speed. Facing a major issue when it comes to speed comparison

Tags: android, performance, mobile, wifi

So for download speed I have basically used the widely present method of keep a timer and download the file as follows. But the speed is very less compared to what Ookla's Speedtest gives:

```
    public class InternetSpeedTest extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    long startTime;
    long endTime;
    private long takenTime;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urlVar) {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try {
            URL ulrn = new URL(urlVar[0]);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) ulrn.openConnection();
            InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            long lengthbmp = con.getContentLength();
            if (null != bmp) {
                endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                return lengthbmp + "";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (result != null) {
            long dataSize = Integer.parseInt(result) / 1024;
            takenTime = endTime - startTime;
            double s = (double) takenTime / 1000;
            double totalspeed = dataSize / s;
            TextView dspeed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.filespeed_tv_ma);
            fileSpeed.setText(Double.toString(totalspeed));
            duration.setText(Long.toString(takenTime));
            filesize.setText(Long.toString(dataSize));
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the latency fine by pinging the host server. How could I implement this in any other way or improve it? Additionally, what can I do for the upload speed.

I read somewhere of using TrafficStats. But that does not give the current speed, right?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you off by a factor of about 8?  It looks like you are using bytes when speed tests usually are in bits/s.

Comment: Thanks for replying but nope. Had thought of that. Its at least twice faster even after factoring 8.